# Instagram-API integration authentication

Tags: ios, swift, oauth-2.0, instagram-api

I'm developing an online platform, where one type of users (User Type 2) create a profile in an web-app and submit data into the web-app. Another user type (User Type 1) is then able to view this data from an iOS-app. See image below for overview.

**I want the User Type 1 to be able to (without logging into instagram) watch User Type 2s Instagram Images.**

I have been playing around with the Instagram-API, registered as a developer, and registered a client app, which is now in sandbox mode. But I find it a bit hard to get started, and a grasp about which user types need to be authenticate.

---

Is it possible to make the iOS-app Authenticate with the API in the background, and then pull images from any instagram user?

If so, what is the simplest way to get started at pulling images down to the iOS-app? Maybe you have some good suggestions or tutorials...

[image: Platform Overview]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, you don't need to authenticate to get a user's photos. You might need it for the iOS SDK, but if you want to use HTTP calls you can get a JSON blob of all the photos by just adding `/media/` after the user address, like so: https://www.instagram.com/dnlrsn/media/.

Obviously, this doesn't allow for interacting with the images, but from what I understood from your question, you don't need that.

Comment: Awesome.. That was what i was looking for :) Do you know how to get more than 20 images returned.. By this method i only get the 20 most recent images..

Comment: You used to be able to add a count parameter to the call, but I believe it has been removed. If so, you might need to authenticate in order to get more. If you want to do it the hacky way, check out this solution for getting an auth token: https://coderwall.com/p/cfgneq/howto-generate-instagram-access_token-for-api-use